# Сделать образ с областей вне разделов

Tags: linux, образ, ddrescue

Я уже сделал образы разделов жёсткого диска.

Как узнать, с каких областей осталось сделать образы, чтобы из всех получившихся файлов можно было собрать полный образ диска?

Comment: а что, с копированием всего блочного устройства есть проблемы? (`sudo cp /dev/sda /путь/к/файлу`).

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, нерационально снова тратить 9 часов на копирование того, что уже есть. Тем более, там были ошибки чтения и за это время их могло и больше стать.

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, добавил логи в вопрос. Хотя, я полагаю, что нужную информацию можно получить и без этих логов.

Comment: *Как узнать, с каких областей осталось сделать образы* — что вы подразумеваете под «областями»? разделы? так тут только у себя самого надо спросить: «какие разделы я уже скопировал, а какие ещё нет?».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, я скопировал все разделы: `/dev/sdb1` и `/dev/sdb2`. Что ещё мне надо скопировать, чтобы я смог из образов собрать полностью образ `/dev/sdb`? В смысле, какие диапазоны `/dev/sdb`.

Comment: насколько я понимаю, больше копировать нечего. надо только [сохранить](http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linux-backup-restore-a-partition-table-with-sfdisk-command/) информацию о начале/конце разделов — пару-тройку строк текста. начальный загрузчик смысла копировать я лично не вижу: при необходимости проще (и, по-моему, «правильнее») восстановить «на месте».

Comment: @alexanderbarakin, мне как раз загрузчик понадобился, поэтому и спрашиваю. Я так понимаю, до `/dev/sdb` мне только начальной области не хватает? Хотя теоретически может быть ещё что-то между разделами и в конце диска. Как узнать точно начальные адреса и размеры для передачи в `ddresque`?

Comment: *мне только начальной области не хватает?* — я не знаю, что такое «начальная область». возможно, вам стоит почитать про mbr и gpt в википедии. свой взгляд на восстановление начального загрузчика (в случае mbr) я уже написал, в случае gpt начальные загрузчики записаны в виде файлов на отдельном разделе. *Как узнать точно начальные адреса и размеры* — написано по приведённой ссылке. вот ещё одна для разнообразия: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/12986/110559

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Использовать fdisk для получения информации о диске:

   ```
   mint@mint ~ $ sudo fdisk -l /dev/sdb

   Disk /dev/sdb: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
   255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders, total 1953525168 sectors
   Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
   Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
   Disk identifier: 0xf3d7eaf1

      Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
   /dev/sdb1   *        2048   524290047   262144000    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   /dev/sdb2       524290048  1953521663   714615808    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
   ```
2. Не скопирована только начальная область - это 2048 секторов размером 512 байт. Перемножаем, получаем размер в 1 МБ.
3. Копируем:

   ```
   ddrescue -d -s 1048576 -v /dev/sdb sdb-1M.img sdb-1M.log
   ```
4. При желании можно убедиться, что далее идёт уже скопированная информация:

   ```
   ddrescue -d -s 1048576 -v -i 1048576 -o 0 /dev/sdb sdb-M2.img sdb-M2.log
   ddrescue -d -s 1048576 -v /dev/sdb1 sdb1-1M.img sdb1-1M.log
   ```

Comment: Забыл проверить хвост...